# How to make ReCAPTCHA v2/v3 show on a react app page

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha

I've read through several posts that have had similar issues with ReCAPTCHA v2 but I'm still unable to figure out the issue.

I followed the npm and google documentation by installing `npm install --save react-google-recaptcha` and including
`<script src="https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>` within the body of the index.html and the page in which i want the reCaptcha to be shown.

But for some reason the reCaptcha will not show up on the page; with or without the code to make the reCaptcha functional.

**Edit**

The reCaptcha v2 was showing on the screen without changing anything with the code for a few moments and disappeared. I restarted VSCode and Github Desktop but the issue hasn't been resolved.

**Contact.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import Stockpic15 from '../img/stockpic15.jpg';
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";
import REACT_APP_SITE_KEY from '../.env'

const Contact = () => {
  
  const onChange = () => {

  }

  return (
  <div className=''>  
   <script src="https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    ....
      <div className='w-2/3 pb-5'>
        <img src={Stockpic15} alt="" />
      </div>
        <form className='flex flex-col justify-center items-center sm:space-y-8 mobile:space-y-10 mobile:text-lg tablet:text-2xl'>
          <input className='contact-input' type='text' name='first-name' placeholder='Your First Name' required/>
          <input className='contact-input' type='text' name='last-name' placeholder='Your Last Name' required/>
          <input className='contact-input' type='email' name='email' placeholder='Your Email Address' required/>
          <textarea className='border-black border-2 rounded-md block w-full resize' name="message" rows="4" placeholder='Message'></textarea>
          <button type="submit" href="#_" className="relative inline-block text-lg group">
            ...
          </button>
           <ReCAPTCHA 
          sitekey={REACT_APP_SITE_KEY}
          oncChange={onChange}
          />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  )}

  export default Contact
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you including the script with reCaptcha two times?

Comment: documentation states it needs to be included in the index.html and wherever the reCAPTCHA is being used https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha.-what-should-i-do

Comment: But you can't use it in both places. If you use it two times second load will delete the first instance. That's probably why reCaptacha displays for a second. This is the time when your component is created and new version if the file is loaded.

Comment: I don't see this information in the documentation. Can you quote the text so I can find it?

Comment: @jcubic deleted the script from the index.html and it worked. I'm not sure whether I misread the documentation or not. Other posts I've seen have even said the same thing so this is odd

Comment: "Yes, please use "www.recaptcha.net" in your code in circumstances when "www.google.com" is not accessible.

First, replace `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>` with `<script src="https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>`
After that, apply the same to everywhere else that uses "www.google.com/recaptcha/" on your site."

Comment: Everywhere else means every other HTML file. Maybe this should be written more clearly. This is the fundamental thing about the web you don't load the same file in multiple places inside the same code.